# Does the laptop power supply the SATA drive from battery even being powered off?

Tags: laptop, ssd, power-supply, sata, battery

I have a Fujitsu Lifebook s762 with a native SSD drive. After a couple of months or so - the SSD became the "brick". I read the [article](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/fast13/fast13-final80.pdf) and remembered, that just before the failure, I shut down the laptop via the 5sec power-button press.

How to check if my laptop still power supplies the SSD even in power-off state? Can the instant power-off be the reason of the SSD failure?

---

**Details.**

The drive is still visible from BIOS, but shows only 1Gb size instead of 256Gb. Some attempts to read the drive lead to no-return operations - and persistent LED light.

Comment: Power failure or hard power offs are not good for any running drive. Have you researched or tried any diagnostics from the Fujitus or the SSD manufacturer?

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes, I have tried the Samsung's CD with firmware update util, but no luck - it doesn't even recognize my drive as eligible.

Comment: That would suggest a critical failure. Might be time to get a replacement.